# Matlab counter stopping the counter at a certain value

Tags: matlab, counter

I am using Matlab and I have implemented a threshold function to tick a counter to do what I need it to do. **I want to know if there is a way that I can make the counter stop counting once it has reached a certain value (maximum or minimum)** That is to say...my counter has reached 40 and now I want no more threshold crossings to be counted.

Comment: don't be shy, show some code

Comment: lol, there is no code to be shown yet

Comment: then show us what you have tried =)

Comment: @user2066364 *I have implemented a threshold function ...*. What, if not code, have you written to implement said function? Please post your work and indicate what the expected and actual results are. As it stands, your question is a prime candidate to be closed as *not a real question*

Comment: there is nothing to show at this point, I'm just roughing out the idea on paper and need to know if it is even possible to stop a counter at a value, otherwise I'll move on to other ideas

Comment: the problem here is nobody is quite sure what you exactly mean, provide a short example of what you want to do, then maybe we'll be able to help :)

Comment: @user2066364 Well then I'm afraid this is not a real question. Can you write code to stop incrementing some counter once it reaches a certain threshold? Of course you can! But beyond that, your question is unanswerable without knowing additional details.

Comment: for instance this is the coding I would use if my idea is even possible

Comment: if handles.magFilt > handles.thresholdValue && handles.isHighFlag == 0  handles.isHighFlag =1      handles.stepcount = handles.stepCount +1

Comment: so despite what kind of code I will use I want to know if it is even possible to stop a counter a at a certain value

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe something like:

```
counter = 0;    
for i = 1:100
    if(condition)
        doSomething();
        counter = counter + 1;
    end
    if(counter == 40)
         break;
    end
end
```

or

```
counter = 0;    
for i = 1:100
    if(condition)
        doSomething();
        if(counter < 40)
            counter = counter + 1;
        end
    end
end
```

?

Depending on what you mean.

Comment: Yes! Thank you, both of those examples will work

Comment: then click the checkmark on the left of the answer to accept it ;)

Answer (score 0):

another (simpler) option, is to use `while` loop:

```
counter=0;
    while counter<=40
         if condition==true
             counter=counter+1
             DoSomething ()
         end
    end
```